# Updating the Progress Bar in the list view

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I have a scenario, In my chat application I want to send photos, photos sending takes time. I have attached a progress bar( horizontal) to show the progress of sending the photo in my application. But I am unable to update the progress bar as it is the item of the custom list view.

Here is my asynchtask to set the progress for Progress Bar but I am not able to get it.

```
 class SendPhotoToFriend extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        String receiver,path = "";

        public SendPhotoToFriend(String path,String receiver) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            this.path = path;
            this.receiver = receiver;

        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ServiceDiscoveryManager sdm = ServiceDiscoveryManager
            .getInstanceFor(connection);

            if (sdm == null)
                sdm = new ServiceDiscoveryManager(connection);

            sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info");
            sdm.addFeature("jabber:iq:privacy");

            // Create the file transfer manager
            FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(
                    connection);
            FileTransferNegotiator.setServiceEnabled(connection, true);

            // Create the outgoing file transfer
            OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager
            .createOutgoingFileTransfer(receiver + "/Smack");

            System.out.println("Receiver of the file is "+receiver+"/smack");

            Log.i("transfere file", "outgoingfiletransfer is created");

            try {
                long total = 0;

                OutgoingFileTransfer.setResponseTimeout(30000);
                transfer.sendFile(new File(path), "Description");
                Log.i("transfere file", "sending file");
                while (!transfer.isDone()) {
                    //Thread.sleep(1000);

                    total+=transfer.getProgress();

                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/transfer.getFileSize()));

                    Log.i("transfere file", "sending file status "
                            + transfer.getStatus() + "progress: "
                            + transfer.getProgress());
                    if (transfer.getStatus() == org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransfer.Status.error) {
                        Log.i("transfere file", "Errorrr isss: "
                                + transfer.getError()+transfer.getPeer());
                        transfer.cancel();
                        break;
                    }
                }

            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.i("transfere file", "sending file done");

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(final String... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);


            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
            final View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_chat_send_chat, null); 
            ProgressBar p_Bar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_image);
            p_Bar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));

            customAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();



        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
```

The progress Bar is the view of the custom list view, I want to update it at the run time.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're inflating the ProgressBar within the onProgress callback. This is absolutely wrong. The ProgressBar should to be added to the view before your AsyncTask starts (inflate and add) and then turn it to be visibile in your AsyncTask constructor. You should also store a reference to the ProgressBar in the AsyncTask (or somehow else in scope by non-static inner class).

In the end your AsyncTask should be looking like this (assuming the ProgressBar is already attached to the view):

```
class SendPhotoToFriend extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    String receiver,path = "";

    ProgressBar progress;

    public SendPhotoToFriend(String path, String receiver, ProgressBar progress) {
        this.path = path;
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.progress = progress;
        this.progress.setVisibility(View.Visible); 
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // You're application logic...
        // ...
        publishProgress((int)((total*100)/transfer.getFileSize()));
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(final Integer... values) {
        this.progress.setProgress(values[0]); 
    }
}
```

Also you don't need to (and shouldn't) call `adapter.notifiyDataSetChanged()` in your onProgres-Callback.

Comment: should I call it from getView method?

Comment: This decision depends a lot on your app's software architecture. There is no wrong or right. It's more like where it makes more sense to call your AsyncTask.. I'm afraid I can't answer this question for you.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose each list item view has a progress bar, if that is the case, you can use getView to get the view for that position, and then call:

```
        View view = customAdapter1.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        ProgressBar p_Bar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_image);
        p_Bar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
```

No need to call customAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();